# how to create tooltip for highlighted strings in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qplaintextedit, qtooltip

I have a QPlainTextEdit and have some words highlighted in it now I want when I hover over it with the mouse it show me a tooltip that has description or something like that about this highlighted word something like this in QT IDE

[image]

but I don't know how to start this so any idea, code or similar project to check this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this case I will create a class that inherits from QPlainTextEdit, reimplement the `event()` method and enable mouse tracking with `setMouseTracking()`

**plaintextedit.h**

```
#ifndef PLAINTEXTEDIT_H
#define PLAINTEXTEDIT_H

#include <QPlainTextEdit>

class PlainTextEdit : public QPlainTextEdit
{
public:
    PlainTextEdit(QWidget *parent=0);

    bool event(QEvent *event);
};

#endif // PLAINTEXTEDIT_H
```

**plaintextedit.cpp**

```
#include "plaintextedit.h"
#include <QToolTip>


PlainTextEdit::PlainTextEdit(QWidget *parent):QPlainTextEdit(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

bool PlainTextEdit::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip)
    {
        QHelpEvent* helpEvent = static_cast<QHelpEvent*>(event);
        QTextCursor cursor = cursorForPosition(helpEvent->pos());
        cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
        if (!cursor.selectedText().isEmpty())
            QToolTip::showText(helpEvent->globalPos(), /*your text*/QString("%1 %2").arg(cursor.selectedText()).arg(cursor.selectedText().length()) );

        else
            QToolTip::hideText();
        return true;
    }
    return QPlainTextEdit::event(event);
}
```

Complete Code: [Here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/ToolTipExample)

Comment: Thank you for this really helpful answer but is there any way to select just highlight word? if there any option cursor.select(QTextCursor::Highlight); or something like that

Comment: @user7179690 If you don't mind translating it back from Python, I did that and more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73184222/435253).

Answer (score 4):

@eyllanesc's answer is great, but I would like to add that if you have viewport margins set, the position must be adjusted because otherwise it will be offset, and an incorrect cursor position reported.

The doc for `cursorForPosition()` states

> returns a QTextCursor at position pos (in **viewport coordinates**). *emphasis added*

```
bool PlainTextEdit::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip)
    {
        QHelpEvent* helpEvent = static_cast<QHelpEvent*>(event);
        
        QPoint pos = helpEvent->pos();
        pos.setX(pos.x() - viewportMargins().left());
        pos.setY(pos.y() - viewportMargins().top());
        
        QTextCursor cursor = cursorForPosition(pos);
        cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
        if (!cursor.selectedText().isEmpty())
            QToolTip::showText(helpEvent->globalPos(), /*your text*/QString("%1 %2").arg(cursor.selectedText()).arg(cursor.selectedText().length()) );

        else
            QToolTip::hideText();
        return true;
    }
    return QPlainTextEdit::event(event);
}
```