# Add a ToolTip with a QSyntaxHighlighter and a QTextCharFormat

Tags: c++, qt, syntax, tooltip

I'm trying to create a little syntax highlighter in Qt, and i want to show a tooltip with the description of the error when the user hoover it.

(I'm subclassing QSyntaxHighlighter)

I've tried the `QTextCharFormat::setToolTip` function, but it didn't work :/
The text is red-underlined as expected, but no tooltip are shown when I hover over it.

Did i miss something ? Or should i use another method ?

```
void CodeHighlighter::highlightBlock(const QString &text)
{
    _errorFormat.setProperty(QTextFormat::TextUnderlineStyle, QTextCharFormat::SpellCheckUnderline);
    _errorFormat.setProperty(QTextFormat::TextUnderlineColor, QColor(Qt::red));
    if (!isLineValid(text.toStdString())) {

        // The following line does not work !
        _errorFormat.setToolTip(QString::fromStdString(getLastError()));

        setFormat(0, text.length(), _errorFormat);
    }
    for (const HighlightingRule &rule : qAsConst(_highlightingRules)) {
        QRegularExpressionMatchIterator matchIterator = rule.pattern.globalMatch(text);
        while (matchIterator.hasNext()) {
            QRegularExpressionMatch match = matchIterator.next();
            QTextCharFormat format = this->format(match.capturedStart());
            format.merge(rule.format);
            setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), format);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen bug report [QTBUG-21553](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-21553)?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly my problem, is this bug still not fixed in Qt5.12.5 ?
If it's the case, what should i do to have my tooltips working ?

Comment: @Azyrod I recommend that you report it again since, as they indicate in the comments, the follow-up was not done because the one who reported did not give the necessary feedback.

Comment: Created a new bug report (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80524), let's see if it get fixed....

Comment: QT hasn't implemented it yet, I believe it might come with future versions. Ref: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtextodfwriter.cpp.html#751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by overriding handling of the `QEvent::ToolTip` and doing the lookup yourself.

I don't have time to rewrite my complete answer in C++, but:

- [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42678659/435253) has C++ code for doing the override but not the lookup. (Basically, on the `QTextEdit` or `QPlainTextEdit`, you `setMouseTracking(True)`, override the `event` method, and hand off to the default implementation unless `event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip`. The other answer to that question points out that you'll also need to correct for margins if you're using them.)
- [This QtCenter post](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45198-can-t-get-format-under-cursor-of-a-QTextEdit?p=206869#post206869) has C++ code to look up the highlighter-applied format in C++... though it does use one deprecated method. (The gist of it is that, in modern Qt, you need to use `cursorForPosition`, then `.block().layout()->formats()` and iterate through, comparing offsets to the cursor's `position()`. `additionalFormats()` being the deprecated method and `formats()` being the modern one.)
- [This SO answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73184222/435253) is a complete, runnable example which demonstrates exposing grammar-checking information as tooltips... it's just written in Python against PyQt.